# Quick mysql_query() question

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I have the following code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE name LIKE '%'$searchTerm'%' OR description LIKE '%'$searchTerm'%';");
```

The only problem is, in pure SQL, such a query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE name LIKE '%asdf%' OR description LIKE '%asdf%'
```

What I'm confused about is how to put my variables into the string properly, normally a variable in a mysql_query would be surrounded by single quotes, but the addition of the single quotes in the SQL itself is confusing me.

I tried concatenating with `.` but I don't think that's a good solution.

Comment: Well first off, this is open to SQL Injection attack... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php.

Comment: I escaped the strings beforehand, the new variable is fine.

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: What's wrong with concatenating with `.` btw?  That would be essentially the exact same thing, and if it's clearer to you, it would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE name LIKE '%$searchTerm%' OR description LIKE '%$searchTerm%';");
```

Why won't you just...

```
echo "SELECT * FROM list WHERE name LIKE '%$searchTerm%' OR description LIKE '%$searchTerm%';"
```

...and see how the query actually will look like..

Comment: you should always do `mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerm)` on any string passed into a statement otherwise it can be a huge security risk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, but I suggest to use a replace function to manage the character "'" into $searchterm. This also allow to avoid sql injections..

Answer (score 0):

This is the clearest way to me, using "." to concatenate:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' OR description LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
```

Try and use that, it should work on what you're trying :)